# How do I do a weighted unigram/bigram/trigram using CountVectorizer with weights (from a column value) instead of count?

Tags: pandas, countvectorizer

My dataset contains a block of text as well as a column with a summarized count and it looks like this:

> **text, count** (column name)
>
> this is my home,100
>
> where am i,10
>
> this is a piece of cake, 2

Code that I have gotten via internet to construct an unigram

```py
def get_top_n_words(corpus, n=None):
    vec = sk.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer().fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]
common_words = get_top_n_words(df['text'], 20)
```

With a standard CountVectorizer, I would produce an unigram that looks like :

> this 2
>
> is 2
>
> my 1
>
> where 1
>
> am 1
> i 1
>
> a 1
>
> piece 1
>
> of 1
>
> cake 1

I am hoping that it can be weighted by its count instead since its a summarized count i.e.:

> this 102
>
> is 102
>
> my 100
>
> where 10
>
> am 10
>
> i 10
>
> a 2
>
> piece 2
>
> of 2
>
> cake 2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using `toarray` method after the `transform` to be able to do matrix multiplication with the count value after:

```
def get_top_n_words(corpus, count, n=None): # add the parameter with the count values
    vec = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer().fit(corpus)
    # here multiply the toarray of transform with the count values
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus).toarray()*count.values[:,None] 
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    # accessing the value in sum_words is a bit different but still related to idx
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()] 
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]

common_words = get_top_n_words(df['text'], df['count'], 20)
print (common_words)
[('this', 102),
 ('is', 102),
 ('my', 100),
 ('home', 100),
 ('where', 10),
 ('am', 10),
 ('piece', 2),
 ('of', 2),
 ('cake', 2)]
```